# Parsing arbitrary context-free grammars, mostly short snippets

Tags: formal-languages, parsers, compilers

I want to parse user-defined domain specific languages. These languages are typically close to mathematical notations (I am not parsing a natural language). Users define their DSL in a BNF notation, like this:

```
expr ::= LiteralInteger
       | ( expr )
       | expr + expr
       | expr * expr
```

Input like `1 + ( 2 * 3 )` must be accepted, while input like `1 +` must be rejected as incorrect, and input like `1 + 2 * 3` must be rejected as ambiguous.

A central difficulty here is coping with ambiguous grammars in a user-friendly way. Restricting the grammar to be unambiguous is not an option: that's the way the language is — the idea is that writers prefer to omit parentheses when they are not necessary to avoid ambiguity. As long as an expression isn't ambiguous, I need to parse it, and if it isn't, I need to reject it.

My parser must work on any context-free grammar, even ambiguous ones, and must accept all unambiguous input. I need the parse tree for all accepted input. For invalid or ambiguous input, I ideally want good error messages, but to start with I'll take what I can get.

I will typically invoke the parser on relatively short inputs, with the occasional longer input. So the asymptotically faster algorithm may not be the best choice. I would like to optimize for a distribution of around 80% inputs less than 20 symbols long, 19% between 20 and 50 symbols, and 1% rare longer inputs. Speed for invalid inputs is not a major concern. Furthermore, I expect a modification of the DSL around every 1000 to 100000 inputs; I can spend a couple of seconds preprocessing my grammar, not a couple of minutes.

What parsing algorithm(s) should I investigate, given my typical input sizes? Should error reporting be a factor in my selection, or should I concentrate on parsing unambiguous inputs and possibly run a completely separate, slower parser to provide error feedback?

(In the project where I needed that (a while back), I used [CYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), which wasn't too hard to implement and worked adequately for my input sizes but didn't produce very nice errors.)

Comment: Especially good error reports seem hard to achieve. You might have more than one local change that leads to an accepted input in case of ambiguous grammars.

Comment: I just answered below. It is a bit awkward to answer to a modification of an old question that already has a well received answer. Obviously I am not supposed to answer in a similar way, but users will read both answers as if they were answering the same question.

Comment: Do you actually expect an error message for ambiguous input, if a user writes `x+y+z`.

Comment: @babou I didn't change the question, I only added clarifications requested in comments (now deleted). For the tiny grammar given here, I haven't specified associativity for `+`, so `x+y+z` is indeed ambiguous hence erroneous.

Comment: Well, it is your last sentence, just added, even if between parentheses. You seem to say: I finally did it with CYK, but it is no longer adequate for some reasons. And I wonder what the precise reasons may be ... You are, *now*, the person with the most experience with your kind of problem and the solution you use, so one would expect more information from you if further answers are to be given.

Comment: ANTLR v4 may work. Quoting [the doc](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/faq/general.md): "[ANTLRv4] takes any grammar that you give it; it just doesn't give a damn."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably the ideal algorithm for your needs is [Generalized LL parsing](http://dotat.at/tmp/gll.pdf), or GLL. This is a very new algorithm (the paper was published in 2010). In a way, it is the Earley algorithm augmented with a graph structured stack (GSS), and using LL(1) lookahead.

The algorithm is quite similar to plain old LL(1), except that it doesn't reject grammars if they are not LL(1): it just tries out all possible LL(1) parses. It uses a directed graph for every point in the parse, which means that if a parse state is encountered that has been dealt with before, it simply merges these two vertices. This makes it suitable for even left-recursive grammars, unlike LL. For exact details on its inner workings, read the paper (it's quite a readable paper, though the label soup requires some perseverance).

The algorithm has a number of clear advantages relevant to your needs over the other general parsing algorithms (that I know of). Firstly, implementation is very easy: I think only Earley is easier to implement. Secondly, performance is quite good: in fact, it becomes just as fast as LL(1) on grammars that are LL(1). Thirdly, recovering the parse is quite easy, and checking whether there is more than one possible parse is as well.

The main advantage GLL has is that it is based on LL(1) and is therefore very easy to understand and debug, when implementing, when designing grammars as well as when parsing inputs. Furthermore, it also makes error handling easier: you know exactly where possible parses stranded and how they might have continued. You can easily give the possible parses at the point of the error and, say, the last 3 points where parses stranded. You might instead opt to try to recover from the error, and mark the production that the parse that got the furthest was working on as 'complete' for that parse, and see if parsing can continue after that (say someone forgot a parenthesis). You could even do that for, say, the 5 parses that got the furthest.

The only downside to the algorithm is that it's new, which means there are no well-established implementations readily available. This may not be a problem to you - I've implemented the algorithm myself, and it was quite easy to do.

Comment: Nice to learn something new. When I needed this (a few years ago, in a project that I'd like to revive some day), I used CYK, largely because it was the first algorithm I found. How does GLL handle ambiguous inputs? The article doesn't seem to discuss this, but I've only skimmed it.

Comment: @Gilles: it builds up a graph structured stack, and all the (potentially exponentially many) parses are compactly represented in this graph, similar to how GLR works. If I recall correctly, the paper mentioned in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374/recovering-a-parse-forest-from-an-earley-parser deals with this.

Comment: @Gilles This 2010 parser seems to have to be programmed
by hand from the grammar, not too adequate if you have several languages, or if you often
modify the language. Techniques for automatic generation from the
grammar of a general parser following any chosen strategy (LL, LR or
others) and producing a forest of all parses have been known for about
40 years. However there are hidden issues regarding complexity and
organization of the graph representing parses. The number of
parses may be worse than exponential: infinite. Error recovery can use
more systematic, parser independent techniques.

Comment: How does GLL relate to LL(*) found in ANTLR?

Answer (score 6):

My company (Semantic Designs) has used [GLR parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) very successfully to do exactly what OP suggest in parsing both domain specific languages, and parsing "classic" programming languages, with our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.  This supports [source-to-source program transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) used for large-scale program restructuring/reverse engineering/forward code generation.  This includes automatic repair of syntax errors in a pretty practical way.  Using GLR as a foundation, and some other changes (semantic predicates, token-set input rather than just token input, ...) we've managed to build parsers for some 40 languages.

As important as the ability to parse full languages instances, GLR has also proven extremely useful in parsing [source-to-source rewrite rules](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html).  These are program fragments with a lot less context than a full program, and thus generally have more ambiguity.  We use special annotations (e.g, insisting that a phrase correspond to a specific grammar nonterminal) to help resolve those ambiguities during/after parsing the rules.  By organizing the GLR parsing machinery and the tools around it, we get parsers for rewrite rules for "free" once we have a parser for its language.  The DMS engine has a built-in rewrite-rule applier that can then be used to apply these rule to carry out desired code changes.

Probably our most spectacular result is the ability to [parse full C++14](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html), in spite of all the ambiguities, using a context-free grammar as a basis.  I note that all the [classic C++ compilers (GCC, Clang) have given up the ability to do this and use hand-written parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320330/120163) (which IMHO makes them much harder to maintain, but then, they're not my problem).  We have used this machinery to [carry out  massive changes to the architecture of large C++ systems.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/)

Performance-wise, our GLR parsers are reasonably fast: tens of thousands of lines per second.  This is well below the state of the art, but we have made no serious attempt to optimize this, and some of the bottlenecks are in the character stream processing (full Unicode).   To build such parsers, we pre-process the context free grammars using something quite close to an LR(1) parser generator; this normally runs on a modern workstation in ten seconds on big grammars the size of C++.  Surprisingly, for very complex languages like modern COBOL and C++, the generation of lexers turns out to take about a minute; some of the DFAs defined over Unicode get pretty hairy.
I just did Ruby (with a full subgrammar for its incredible regexps) as a finger-exercise; DMS can process its lexer and grammar together in about 8 seconds.

Comment: @Raphael: The "massive changes" link points to a set of academic-style technical papers, including a few on C++ architecture re-engineering, one on the DMS engine itself (rather old but describes the basics well), and one on the exotic topic of design capture and reuse, which was the original motivation for DMS (still unachieved, unfortunately, but DMS has turned out to be pretty useful anyway).

Answer (score 1):

There are many general context-free parser that can parse ambiguous
sentences (according to an ambiguous grammar). They come under various
names, notably dynamic-programming or chart parsers. The best known
one, and next to simplest, is probably the CYK parser that you have
been using. That generality is needed since you have to handle
multiple parses and may not know till the end whether you are dealing
with an ambiguity or not.

From what you say, I would think that CYK is not such a bad choice.
You probably do not have much to gain by adding predictiveness (LL or
LR), and it may actually have a cost by discriminating computations
that should be merged rather than discriminated (especially in the LR
case). They may also have a corresponding cost in the size of the
parse forest that is produced (which may have a role in ambiguity
errors). Actually, while I am not sure how to compare formally the
adequacy of the more sophisticated algorithms, I do know that CYK does
give good computation sharing.

Now, I do not believe there is much literature on general CF parsers for
ambiguous grammars that should only accept unambiguous input. I do not
recall seeing any, probably because even for technical documents, or
even programming languages, syntactic ambiguity is acceptable as long
as it can be resolved by other means (e.g. ambiguity in ADA
expressions).

I am actually wondering why you want to change your algorithm, rather
than stick to what you have. That might help me understand what kind
of change could best help you.  Is it a speed issue, is it the
representation of parses, or is it the error detection and recovery?

The best way to represent multiple parses is with a shared forest,
which is simply a context-free grammar that generates only your input,
but with exactly all the same parse trees as the DSL grammar. That
makes it very easy to understand and process. For more details, I
suggest you look at [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/is-there-a-favoured-data-structure-for-storing-ambiguous-parse-trees-in-natural/6120#6120) I gave on the linguistic site.  I do
understand that you are not interested in getting a parse forest, but
a proper representation of parse forest can help you give better
messages as to what the ambiguity problen is. It could also help you
decide that the ambiguity does not matter in some cases
(associativity) if you wantd to do that.

You mention the processing time constraints of your DSL grammar, but
give no hint as to its size (which does not means that I could answer
with figures it you did).

Some error processing can be integrated in these general CF algorithms
in simple ways. But I would need to understand what kind of error
processing you expect to be more affirmative. Would you have some examples.

I am a bit ill at ease to say more, because I do not understand what
are really your motivations and constraints. On the basis of what you
say, I would stick to CYK (and I do know the other algorithms and some
of their properties).